# grammatical use of "that"

Tags: slogan

I'm making a slogan for a website and I really would like to use the word "that" in it.

example slogans

```
stuff that you would say cool

stuff that you would say amazing
```

are these slogans grammatically correct?

Comment: You may need the verb *is* if I understand correctly: *stuff that you would say **is** cool*.

Answer (score 1):

These slogans are not grammatically correct, but not because of "that".  The problem is the verb "say", which requires a preposition.  So you could use

> stuff *in response to which* you would say "cool"

but you probably want something more like

> stuff that you would call cool

In the latter case, the "that" is optional.